# Write query to get sum of multiplicaion of two column

Tags: mysql

I have written query to get sum of multiplication of two column.

```
select *,sum(op.qty*op.price) as total from `order` as o 
join order_products as op on op.order_id = o.order_id
where o.user_id = 5 and o.order_id = 10 group by op.order_product_id
```

my output looks like
[image]

Here, As shown in image I want all record as well as sum of total.

So, what should I have to do?

Comment: Can you show sample data and the expected output? Helps in understanding the question..

Answer (score 0):

I have change my query as

```
select
t1.*,
t2.total
FROM
(
  SELECT op.*
  FROM `order` AS o JOIN order_products AS op ON op.order_id = o.order_id
  WHERE o.user_id = 5 AND o.order_id = 10
) as t1
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT sum(op.qty * op.price) as total
  FROM `order` AS o JOIN order_products AS op ON op.order_id = o.order_id
  WHERE o.user_id = 5 AND o.order_id = 10
) as t2
ON 1 = 1
```

And it gives result like this

[image]

And this query run perfect.